# ActiveMQ Artemis: creating queue programmatically from smallrye-reactive-messaging (AMQP)

Tags: amqp, activemq-artemis, smallrye-reactive-messaging

My Quarkus microservice is using the AMQP connector in the smallrye reactive messaging library to produce messages to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker running from the `vromero/activemq-artemis:2.16.0-alpine` Docker image. The [reactive messaging library](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/2.8/amqp/amqp.html) documentation mentions the possibility to use dynamic address names. I'm using following (Kotlin) code in my REST resource:

```kotlin
    @Inject
    @Channel("task-finished")
    lateinit var taskFinishedEmitter: MutinyEmitter<String>

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    fun doSomethingAndInform(@RestForm customerId: String): Uni<String> {

       // leaving out the actual messageText computation...

       val messageText: String = "DUMMY MESSAGE"
       val metadata: OutgoingAmqpMetadata = OutgoingAmqpMetadata.builder()
          .withDurable(true)
          .withCorrelationId(customerId)
          .withAddress("anycast://my-custom-address")
          .build()

       val message: Message<String> = Message.of(messageText,
            {
                logger.info("message acked")
                CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)
            },
            {
                logger.info("message nacked: {}", it.message)
                CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)
            }
       )

       taskFinishedEmitter.send(message.addMetadata(metadata))
       return Uni.createFrom().item("DONE")
    }
```

The connector is defined in the `application.properties`:

```
amqp-host=localhost
amqp-port=5672
amqp-username=adm
amqp-password=***

mp.messaging.outgoing.task-finished.connector=smallrye-amqp
```

ActiveMQ Artemis indeed creates the `my-custom-address` address dynamically however it doesn't create any queue bound to it and the message ends up being **unrouted**.

The `broker.xml` config file contains in the `core` section

```xml
<acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;anycastPrefix=anycast://</acceptor>
<address-setting match="#">
   <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
</address-settings>
```

I tried passing the queue name along with the address

```kotlin
.withAddress("anycast://my-custom-address::my-queue")
```

but it didn't make any difference.

What is missing for the queue being created programmatically and the message being delivered to it? Also why does Artemis acknowledge the message when it gets lost (unrouted)?

Update: attaching a screenshot from the Artemis web interface
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ActiveMQ Artemis will treat messages sent by AMQP clients as *multicast* (i.e. pub/sub). The semantics of multicast dictate that every message published to the broker will be dispatched to every subscriber. However, since there are no subscribers the message is simply discarded (i.e. unrouted).

Since you're prefixing your address with `anycast://` you should configure that prefix on the "amqp" `acceptor` in `broker.xml` using the `anycastPrefix` parameter, e.g.:

```xml
<acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;anycastPrefix=anycast://</acceptor>
```

You could also change the default routing types used for auto-created resources, e.g.:

```xml
<address-setting match="my-custom-address">
   <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
   <default-queue-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-queue-routing-type>
</address-settings>
```

Comment: I've already had the anycast prefix parameter defined in the amqp acceptor tag and Artemis creates an address of type anycast but 0 queues and the unrouted message count is 1. I've just added your suggested `address-setting` for `my-custom-address` and still no queue is created. I've updated my question with a screenshot of Artemis web interface.

Comment: That's odd. I just tested with an AMQP client in the ActiveMQ Artemis test-suite and the address was created as multicast at first until I changed the default configuration at which point both the address and queue were created as anycast and the message was routed appropriately. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: this project contains the minimal reproducible example along with instructions on how to run it: https://github.com/theWestIsTheBest/pigeon I even used Wireshark to see what is being sent to the message broker to better understand AMQP :)

Comment: I've removed the `anycast://`from the address name: `.withAddress("my-custom-address")` and it's creating an anycast queue now! Thank you!